# get the column's header name

Tags: java, excel, xssf

I have to read all the cells of any column with header name "ABCD".
I can get the values iterated over to any row but am stuck with a situation to get the column header name. I can also get the column header name using the excel as database:
String sSQL = "Select * from [MAIN$]";  //sql statement
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

```
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=22;Dbq= " + XLSPath + ";ReadOnly=0;");
        Statement stmnt = conn.createStatement(); 
        rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sSQL);  //sql statement

        Statement stmnt1 = null;
        //Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=22;DBQ= " + XLSPath + ";ReadOnly=false;");
        stmnt1 = conn.createStatement();
        stmnt1 = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

String ctvstr = "Update [MAIN$] SET EXCEL_Heading=" + "'" + ColValues + "'" + " Where ID=" +  j;
                    stmnt1.executeUpdate(ctvstr);

I have to do the same thing in Java + xssf + poi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the Column name and iterate over to the respective column with its header name for example "ABCD" , the solution to get this is to find the cell in first row with string matching "ABCD" and then iterate over to respective column(with the cell number of "ABCD")

Answer (score 0):

I think you need ResultSetMetaData, ckeck this site
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html

Comment: above link is very helpful, but isn't the scope of "resultSet" limited to windows only.